# window.onload works fine with aspx page, but not in regular html

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, onload, xhtml-1.0-strict

Could someone please explain to me why `window.onload` works fine in aspx, but not in xhtml?

This `window.onload` example works fine in aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
      //handles the collapse of submenu items on navigation side menu

 function toggle() {

     document.getElementById('node4').style.display = '';

 }

 window.onload = toggle;

//]]>
 </script>
```

Yet this `window.onload` example doesn't work in XHTML 1.0 strict. (It doesn't instantly fire `countDownClock` when page is loaded ):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   //handles the collapse of submenu items on navigation side menu

   function countDownClock() {
       today = new Date();
       openingDay = new Date();
       openingDay.setMonth(2, 23);
       (today > openingDay) ? openingDay.setFullYear(2013) : openingDay.setFullYear();
       openingDay.setHours(9, 0, 0, 0);
       document.getElementById("mallclock").dayNow.value = showDate(today);
       document.getElementById("mallclock").timeNow.value = showTime(today);

       var daysLeft = dayDiff(today, openingDay);
       var hoursLeft = hoursDiff(today, openingDay);
       var minutesLeft = minutesDiff(today, openingDay);

       daysLeft = ((hoursLeft - 24) >= 0) ? daysLeft + (hoursLeft / 24) : daysLeft;
       hoursLeft = ((hoursLeft - 24) >= 0) ? hoursLeft - ((hoursLeft / 24) * 24) : hoursLeft;
       hoursLeft = ((minutesLeft - 60) >= 0) ? hoursLeft + (minutesLeft / 60) : hoursLeft;
       minutesLeft = ((minutesLeft - 60) >= 0) ? minutesLeft - ((minutesLeft / 60) * 60) : minutesLeft;

       document.getElementById("mallclock").days.value = daysLeft;
       document.getElementById("mallclock").hours.value = hoursLeft;
       document.getElementById("mallclock").minutes.value = minutesLeft;

   }

   window.onload = countDownClock;

 //]]>
</script>
```

It only fires the body event, which is set to show `countDownClock` 1 minute later

```
<body onload = "setInterval('countDownClock()', 60000)">
```

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens when you run it, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: when I run it, it only fires the                                  <body onload = "setInterval('countDownClock()', 60000)"> that I have. so 1 minute after the page loads I see what I want...But what I want it to do is instantly show up when the page loads AND THEN re-call the function every minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, the edit made all the difference.

A page can only have one handler for the `load` event, so if you add one using `window.onload` and add another one using the `body onload` attribute, only one of them will work.

Put both actions in the same handler:

```
window.onload = function(){
  countDownClock();
  window.setInterval(countDownClock, 60000);
};
```